# Web Deployment Agent Service returns a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am attempting to deploy a web site remotely using the Web Deployment Agent Service.  When running the cmd file generated by Visual Studio using /m command switch, I get the following error:

> Error Code: ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC 
>   More Information: Could not connect to the remote computer ("x.x.x.x") using the specified process ("Web Deployment Agent Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Deployment Agent Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.
>   Error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

I checked the link and it has 3 suggestions.  Make sure the service is running which it is.  Make sure that the user is an administrator which it is and make sure the firewall isn't blocking the traffic which it isn't.

I turned on wireshark to see if that would get any clues and I get the initial 401 Unauthorized from the deployment service and then the client makes the request again using NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE.  That is when the deployment service returns the 500.

I am guessing it is some sort of permissions thing on my deployment server, but I can't narrow it down.  Does anyone know where the Web Deployment Agent Service logs or how to turn on logging for that service?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this article about setting up Web Deployment server
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722796(v=ws.10).aspx

in step 6 it points to this artical about setting up logging adn tracing
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461173(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: That is the Web Management Service.  I am trying to get the Web Deployment Agent Service working.  Is there an equivalent article for the Web Deployment Agent Service?

Answer (score 0):

Did it work previously? I've had the same issue, WebDeploy suddenly broke down after a reboot on 19th december, some windows update. I've had to remove WebDeploy 3.6 from program and Features and then to uninstall the IIS Webmanagement Role through the server manager.

After rebooting i've installed Web Deploy 3.6 for Hosting Servers through Web Platform installer again and it worked again.

Comment: No it has never worked for deployment service.  I might try and reinstall and see it that fixes it.

Comment: @DarrylDavidson at that chance, i'm not sure if it was involved in the solution but i've noticed that the windows authentication support feature for IIS wasn't installed so i've added that feature before re-installing everything.